# Layout Memory leak?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, android-memory

i am a junior android developer. For android UI design, i think most of android developer will use XML for layout design. Today, my senior developer said that he does not use XML for layout design. All UI design use code to generate. The reason he said is that the layout resource is not released by Android automatically.Using JNI release the layout resource . He does not tell you in detail because he think i am very junior.

I want to ask whether he is true or not. I have no idea for his point of view. But, i make sure that his code cannot reuse. Also, how the Android release the layout resource in its life cycle.

Thanks.

Comment: You should prefer using XML for designing layouts as it gives you a tonn of advantages. And I doubt it can lead you to any kind of memory leaks.

Comment: this is so not true. There's no memory leak when designing layouts through xml. He might be joking with you.

Comment: @Egor: yes, i think so. It is no sense to hard coding the layout.

Comment: @Waqas: Do you have any idea for checking memory in eclipse? Then i can prove for him.

Comment: When you install *ADT* in Eclipse, it provides you **DDMS** which is the best tool for observing memory, threads, and other useful operations. Through this, you can keep track of memory used by your application's process. Moreover, simply show him @CommonsWare answer because he's one of the Android-Guru on SA  :)

Comment: Thanks. I just want to clarify his talk. If i show to him, i will always aim at me =[

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The reason he said is that the layout resource is not released by Android automatically

The widgets created by inflating a layout resource are "released by Android automatically" when those widgets are removed from the activity or if the activity is destroyed. In other words, widgets are garbage-collected the same as any other Java object. And, this holds true no matter whether the widgets were created using layout resources or not.

It is conceivable that the parsed XML of the layout resource is cached by the process, so if the same layout is needed again, the parsing step can be skipped. This will not be very much memory. Avoiding XML layout resources to avoid such small memory caching is very short-sighted, not what I would expect from a true "senior developer".

> Using JNI release the layout resource

JNI has nothing to do with layout resources. JNI has nothing to do with widgets, either.

> He does not tell you in detail because he think i am very junior.

He is welcome to document his findings, providing proof for his claims and justifications for his decision.

Comment: Great! But, how do you know layout resource is cached?

Comment: A great answer. Can i ask you a question? I need to cooperate with IOS developer. He does not know how android do UI design. But, he make a very dynamics UI. Would you mind go to this link to answer me? [Link:] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563370/how-do-you-design-this-layout-simple  Thanks.

Comment: @user1535426: "But, how do you know layout resource is cached?" -- you spend several hours hunting through the Android source code to determine if Android indeed caches parsed layout XML resources. Personally, I do not know if they are cached or not.