# How do you design this layout simple?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

i need to cooperate with IOS developer. He does not know how Android work in layout system. He design a very dynamics UI. Please see my link.

[Link:] http://dl.dropbox.com/u/78582670/layoutdesign.png

Remarks: Orange rectangle mean image buttons.

In this layout, there exist two main views. For View 1, it is a list view. When clicking a item, a View 2 will animate. View 2 move from right to left. Also, it cover the View 1 a bit. After this translation finish, the orange Rect also animate. They move from bottom to the relative position.

I talk to them. If i do that design, the layout cannot be reused. Secondly, i don't want to hard code for playing animation and the UI design.

They think everything is possible and easy to do = =|||.

If you are me, how do you design it?

Here is my solution, but View 2 cannot cover View 1.

```
public class EducationSystemActivity extends Activity 
{
ImageButton mButton1 = null;
ImageButton mButton2 = null;
ImageButton mButton3 = null;
ImageButton mButton4 = null;
ImageButton mButton5 = null;

OnClickListener mImageButtonClickListner = new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.imageButton1:{
                Fragment fragment = new TestFragment2();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fragment_slide_left_enter,
                        R.animator.fragment_slide_left_exit,
                        R.animator.fragment_slide_right_enter,
                        R.animator.fragment_slide_right_exit);
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, fragment);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
                Toast.makeText(EducationSystemActivity.this, "Button1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.imageButton2:{
                Toast.makeText(EducationSystemActivity.this, "Button2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.imageButton3:{
                Toast.makeText(EducationSystemActivity.this, "Button3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.imageButton4:{
                Toast.makeText(EducationSystemActivity.this, "Button4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.imageButton5:{
                Toast.makeText(EducationSystemActivity.this, "Button5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    mButton1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    mButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    mButton3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    mButton4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
    mButton5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);

    mButton1.setOnClickListener(mImageButtonClickListner);
    mButton2.setOnClickListener(mImageButtonClickListner);
    mButton3.setOnClickListener(mImageButtonClickListner);
    mButton4.setOnClickListener(mImageButtonClickListner);
    mButton5.setOnClickListener(mImageButtonClickListner);


    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, new TestFragment1());
    ft.commit();

}

}
```

TestFragment2:

```
public class TestFragment2 extends Fragment
{
LayoutInflater mInflater = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("TestFragment1", "onCreateView");
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment2, container, false);
}

@Override
public Animator onCreateAnimator(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {
    Log.d("TestFragment2", "onCreateAnimator transit:" + transit + " enter:" + enter + " nextAnim:" + nextAnim);
    Animator set = null;
    if(enter){
        set = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this.getActivity(), R.animator.fragment_slide_left_enter);
        set.addListener(new AnimatorListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) 
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) 
            {
                Log.d("TestFragment2", "onAnimationEnd()");
                addAnimationSubMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) 
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) 
            {
                Log.d("TestFragment2", "onAnimationStart()");
            }

        });
    }
    else{
        set = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this.getActivity(), R.animator.fragment_slide_left_exit);
    }
    return set; 
}


private void addAnimationSubMenu()
{
    ViewGroup submenu_frame = (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.submenu_frame);
    mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_submenu, submenu_frame, true);
    View submenu_layout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.submenu_layout);
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getActivity(), R.anim.slide_bottom_to_top);
    submenu_layout.startAnimation(anim);
}
}
```

testfragment2.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFEFE00"
android:padding="0dp"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:text="@string/test2" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/submenu_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_drawable">
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_submenu1.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/submenu_layout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/menu_item1"
    android:src="@drawable/speech_bubble2x" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/menu_item2"
    android:src="@drawable/newspaper2x" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/menu_item3"
    android:src="@drawable/trolley2x" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/menu_item4"
    android:src="@drawable/refresh2x" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/menu_item5"
    android:src="@drawable/house2x" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Possible you have to use fragments use http://actionbarsherlock.com/  this library will help you to get your requirement and http://xrigau.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/using-an-actionbar-in-your-application-with-actionbarsherlock/ this tutorial will help you to implement the library.

Comment: Thanks. I use this library before. But, how do i layout to add fragment?

Comment: you can find many tutorials to how to use fragments in android 3.0 use the same code but some of the methods are different in this library any just use those codes to make yours .http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html .